# automatically scroll down page when div opens with toggle

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a hidden div whichs is opened/closed via a slidetoggle function (see below) when I click on a button. This works well. However, I want that the bottom of my page scrolls down/up automaticcaly when the div is opened/closed. The bottom of my page must be aligned with the bottom of the opened div + some extra margin below the div, such that the opened div is seen by the visitor of my page. How can I do this?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#button_toggle_XRT").click(function() {
        $( "#XRT_overview").slideToggle(1000);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your div in another div. You'll have to do some additional CSS with the outer div, but that should keep everything in check. Now, you'll apply the `slideToggle()` to the inner div, not the outer div. I've made a jsBin to help out:

http://jsbin.com/pacecibugu/edit?html,output

It's going to look something like this:

```
<div style="height:200px;background-color:gray;" id="clickableDiv">

    <div style="height:190px;background-color:lightgray;" id="toggledDiv">
      <p>Here's my div</p>
    </div>

</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#clickableDiv").click(function() {
         $("#toggledDiv").toggle();
      });

    });

</script>
```